# Getting JSON key as a text

Tags: karate

Trying to get the json key text within karate feature script.

HI, I am new to karate and going through all the documentation of karate..

When I am getting `GET` response as show below in the code, I am not sure what all keys a response will have. So whenever in the response there is key text is `domain_name` , then I want to retrieve `domain_code`

```
{
"status":"SUCCESS",
"totalCount":1,
"statusCode":"OK",
"ResultData":{
    "data":[
        {"domain_code":"X3","domain_name":"BMW"}, 
        {"domain_code":"Q5","domain_name":"AUDI"}, 
        {"domain_code":"G450","domain_name":"LEXUS"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Read the docs if any part is not clear, starting with JsonPath:

```
* def response = 
"""
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "totalCount": 1,
  "statusCode": "OK",
  "ResultData": {
    "data": [
        {"domain_code": "X3", "domain_name": "BMW" }, 
        {"domain_code": "Q5", "domain_name": "AUDI" }, 
        {"domain_code": "G450", "domain_name": "LEXUS" }
    ]
  }
}
"""
* def data = get[0] response..data[?(@.domain_name)]
* def keys = karate.keysOf(data)
* keys.remove('domain_name')
* print keys[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. It's working.. I saw you are using get[0]. how to traverse through all the items? I tried get[*] and it's not working. I am sure this may not be the correct syntax. I will go and check the documentation.